# How to set a custom URL for a file in IPFS?

Tags: blockchain, ipfs, contract

I am trying to start using IPFS and I face with an issue that each file has its own CID in the URL.

How can I generate a custom url from the CID, so I can access a content with `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/images/1/car/2` or something like that? Otherwise I will have to store these links in a map in my contract.

Answer (score 0):

Please, give more info about your problem:

- provider
- IPFS library
- example of CID
- full code if it possible

If I understand it correctly, you can just concatenate strings based on already uploaded file.

```
const linkToIpfsFile: AddResult = await this.ipfsClient.add({ content: JSON.stringify(nftObj) });
const cid: string = linkToIpfsFile.cid;
const cidConverted = new CID(cid.toString()).toV1().toString('base32');
const ipfsMetadataUrl = 'https://' + cidConverted + '.ipfs.infura-ipfs.io/';
```

interface

```
export interface AddResult {
  path: string,
  cid: string,
  mode?: number,
  mtime?: { secs: number, nsecs: number },
  size: number,
}
```

Comment: If you need OP to provide more information, you should ask for it in a comment; don't provide an answer guessing at a solution.